# Error on Zookeeper cluster mode with Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to deploy a zookeeper cluster using docker on differents hosts. I use the next docker-compose where I run zoo1 in host1 zoo2 in host2 and zoo3 in host3.

```
version: '2'
services:
    zoo1:
        image: 31z4/zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 2181:2181
            - 2888:2888
            - 3888:3888
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 1
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=host1-IP:2888:3888 server.2=host2-IP:2888:3888 server.3=host3-IP:2888:3888

    zoo2:
        image: 31z4/zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 2182:2181
            - 2888:2888
            - 3888:3888
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 2
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=host1-IP:2888:3888 server.2=host2-IP:2888:3888 server.3=host3-IP:2888:3888

    zoo3:
        image: 31z4/zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 2183:2181
            - 2888:2888
            - 3888:3888
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 3
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=host1-IP:2888:3888 server.2=host2-IP:2888:3888 server.3=host3-IP:2888:3888
```

The code is added from: https://github.com/31z4/zookeeper-docker

I just try with the next docker-compose too, and adding zoo1, zoo2 and zoo3 to the /etc/hosts file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    zoo1:
        image: 31z4/zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 2181:2181
            - 2888:2888
            - 3888:3888
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 1
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888

    zoo2:
        image: 31z4/zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 2182:2181
            - 2888:2888
            - 3888:3888
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 2
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zooo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888

    zoo3:
        image: 31z4/zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 2183:2181
            - 2888:2888
            - 3888:3888
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 3
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

But it is not working, if I check the status:

```
./bin/zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /conf/zoo.cfg
Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. See [ask] and [mcve] for details on what constitutes a good question.

Comment: @HoriaComan Thanks is just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left part of an exposing port is the local port of the host, that can only be used once. Also, you don't need to expose ports for containers interconnection, as they are in the same network.

So remove the left part `2888:2888`, leave it as this: `2888`, then docker will find a free port in the host (use `docker ps` to find out it). Or directly remove the `ports` directive if you don't need exposing ports.

```
version: '2'
services:
    zoo1:
        image: 31z4/zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 2181
            - 2888
            - 3888
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 1
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888

    zoo2:
        image: 31z4/zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 2181
            - 2888
            - 3888
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 2
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888

    zoo3:
        image: 31z4/zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 2181
            - 2888
            - 3888
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 3
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

Comment: Really thanks, but I just used on different hosts so thats ports are free, finally it works after some minutes running.